# Have a read only git repo that pulls from other repos

Tags: git

So in our work environment we use Stash and we all have access via AD. Right now the problem I'm having is writing some cookbooks that can do a git checkout of a repository without having to use my own account and/or creating a read only AD account. I was thinking of maybe having something along the lines of having a repo that is public (anyone can clone from), in which this repo pulls from certain other repos when changes are seen or at certain intervals.

Not sure if something like this is even possible but it would be awesome to not have to maintain two repos (internal and public) for the same content (chef recipes).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). It is a solution to make a link between repos.